# Converting an ArrayList of Strings into A BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader

How do I converting an ArrayList of strings into a BufferedReader? I'm open to making the ArrayList as an Input Stream instead, but I want an easy way to add strings into the data structure that will eventually be captured by the BufferedReader.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Reading an `ArrayList` is far simpler than fetching data from a buffered reader.

Comment: Because the function which I am trying to test requires a BufferedReader as input.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This may not be the quickest or most efficient way, but this is the first thing I thought of:

```
// Assume the ArrayList is named stringList
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
for(String current : stringList) {
    buffer.append(current).append("\n");
}

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(buffer.toString()));
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a one-liner. It works with a List of Strings too:

```
BufferedReader buffer = 
new BufferedReader( new StringReader(  String.join(  "\n", stringList  )) );
```